# Проблема с пробелами при шифровании методом Виженера на python

Tags: python, шифрование

```
from itertools import cycle

alp = 'абвгґдеєжзиіїйклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюя '
text = 'поліалфавітний шифр'.lower()
keytext = 'ключ'

def encode_vijn(text, keytext):
    f = lambda arg: alp[(alp.index(arg[0])+alp.index(arg[1])%33)%33]
    return ''.join(map(f, zip(text, cycle(keytext))))

result = []
for words in text.split(" "):
    result.append(encode_vijn(words, keytext))
print(" ".join(result))
```

Вроде шифрует правильно, но только пока там одно слово. После пробела ключ начинает использоваться с начала. Помогите исправить

Comment: Ну так после пробела идёт новое шифрование, потому что в цикле каждое слово шифруется отдельно. Убери цикл и шифруй весь текст целиком